# Objective-C method conflicts with optional requirement method Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

After the Xcode update, the compiler began to throw an error on the working code (both functions are in the AppDelegate.swift).

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool 
{
    FBLoginView.self
    FBProfilePictureView.self
    return true
}
```

With error:

> /Users/../AppDelegate.swift:14:11: Objective-C method 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' provided by method 'application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

And second

```
func application(application: UIApplication,        
                            openURL url: NSURL,
                            sourceApplication: NSString?,
                            annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication as! String)
    return wasHandled
}
```

with error

> /Users/../AppDelegate.swift:25:11: Objective-C method 
>   'application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:' provided by method 'application(*:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(*:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

I understand that most likely I should like you to stick together somehow these two functions into one. I do not understand why this code suddenly stopped working in 6.3, despite the fact that it worked in 6.2.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why the compiler is throwing the error, however I do see a difference in the default Swift version of those same methods. Perhaps you could replace the function declaration with those created with a normal Swift project:

## 1

`func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

## 2

`func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool`

I'd recommend replacing your method declarations with the above to see if it compiles now.

---

**EDIT 1 (9/21/2015): I've confirmed these are now up to date for Xcode 7's public release. They removed the optional (`annotation: AnyObject?`) and made it (`annotation: AnyObject`), in declaration #2.**

Comment: For XCode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Answer (score 24):

The type of the **launchOptions** parameter of the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function was changed in XCode 6.3:

"launchOptions: NSDictionary?" has become "launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?"

Just change your function header to match the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It appears the changes were updated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It gave me a headache while trying to solve a number of issues while reading RayWenderlich's 'iOS8 by Tutorials v1.2' using Xcode-6.4

Answer (score 5):

You should also make sure you are using the correct type. Use **String** instead of **NSString**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does help answer the question. This error will happen when you use a NSString instead of a String.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding that method again from Xcode completions. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

launchOptions have been changed; try changing out "launchOptions: NSDictionary?" to "launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?"

Hope this helps!