# Using FXForms in Swift Project updated to iOS sdk 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, fxforms

This is my first question on stack overflow so please excuse if I miss any mannerisms.....

My Swift App uses the [FXForms](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms) Cocoa Pod

It's an OBJ-C framework I'm using with my Swift app.   Everything compiled fine before updating Xcode today.  Now I am getting this error:

**"Objective-C method 'fields' provided by method 'fields()' conflicts with optional requirement method 'fields()' in protocol 'FXForm'e**

Any ideas?  Happy to provide source code, etc.

Thanks for any help,

ztb

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the update in Swift syntax. Look into the code if you use `NSDictionary` and replace with `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. Same for `NSString` replace with `String`. In most cases this will fix this issue.

You could try in Xcode to run Edit - Convert - To latest Swift Syntax. I did it on my project and no changes were made. But it is worth a try!

Have a look at this post which handles a similar error:

[Objective-C method conflicts with optional requirement method Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460472/objective-c-method-conflicts-with-optional-requirement-method-swift)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that you fixed this!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this:

```
func fields() -> NSArray {

    return [
```

with this:

```
func fields() -> [AnyObject}! {

        return [
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in swift 1.2:

```
func fields() -> [AnyObject]! {
    return fieldsArr as [AnyObject]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed. Other solutions fooled the compiler but I lost some formatting from the FXForms Fields Array.  This worked perfectly.