# Get string value as a return type in 'captureOutput'

Tags: ios, swift

This is the function I'm using to read a QR code:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!){
```

I want to return the QR code text but Xcode throws this error when I add a return type as String to the above function.

**Objective-C method 'captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:' provided by method 'captureOutput(*:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'captureOutput(*:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:)' in protocol 'AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate'**

How can return a QR code as a string?

var code = readQRCode()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C method conflicts with optional requirement method Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460472/objective-c-method-conflicts-with-optional-requirement-method-swift)

Answer (score -1):

> Xcode throws this error when I add a return type as String to the above function

Because the function `captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:` already exists (as part of the AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate protocol) and *doesn't*
return a String. You can't *change* it. It doesn't belong to you. The way it is defined is the way it is defined.

Comment: Call a method or set a property from within your `captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:`.